# Subsets of $M$ such that $2M \cong M$

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I have a question concerning cardinal arithmetic in $\sf{ZF}$.
Write $ X \cong Y$ if there is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$.

Let $M$ be a set such that $2M\cong M$.
Can one show, in $\sf{ZF}$, that for any infinite subset $X$ of $M$, we also have $2X \cong X$ ?

Thank you :)

Comment: It would make more sense to write $X \cong Y$.

Comment: @user170039: The edit is quite redundant. It doesn't really improve the readability, nor does it have any significant consequences for the formatting of the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

Simply because if $A$ is a set of any cardinality, there is $B$ such that:

1. $|A|\leq|B$, and
2. $|B|+|B|=|B|$, and in fact we can require $|B\times B|=|B|$.

Just take $B=A^\omega$, all the functions from $\omega$ to $A$. Then we have that $|B|=|A|^{\aleph_0}$ and therefore $|B\times B|=|A|^{\aleph_0+\aleph_0}=|A|^{\aleph_0}=|B|$.

Now take $A$ to be some set such that $|A|<2|A|$, e.g. an infinite Dedekind-finite set, and you get a counterexample.

(As Joel remarks, taking $B=\omega\times A$ is sufficient for $|B|+|B|=|B|$. However, it might not be enough if we want $|B|^2=|B|$.)

---

Another fun way of proving this is to prove that for every $\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ satisfies that $|V_\alpha|=2|V_\alpha|=|V_\alpha|^2$. So if the additivity would be hereditary (for infinite subsets), it would be provable in $\sf ZF$ that for every infinite cardinal, $|A|+|A|=|A|$. But this is not true, of course.

Comment: Nice answer! It seems that you could also use $B=A^{<\omega}$.

Comment: Joel, yes, but that requires typing more characters, and the argument involves slightly subtler cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: It seems that $\omega\times A$ would also work, for the $B+B$ case, right?

Comment: Yes. That is true. We can even prove a nice equivalence that $\frak p+p=p$ if and only if $\aleph_0\cdot\frak p=p$. So taking $\omega\times A$ is "the obvious way to go". But I wanted to go big and even get a product, and then you need to do a bit better.

Comment: Oh. What a beautiful counter example. Thank you so much :)